# Must I keep my Yahoo! application id secret?

Tags: yahoo-api

I have created a Yahoo! application id so I can use the Yahoo! GeoPlanet™ API. Must I keep this application id secret, or may I just use it in client-side JavaScript and binaries? I couldn't find this in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

No, for this API you don't need to worry about keeping the app id secret. It's only used for rate-limiting and tracking purposes. These app id are also free, so there's no incentive for someone to grab yours and try to squat on your rate limits or anything.